# How do I get the default NLCD symbology back after clipping/projecting?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, legend, arcgis-10.5, nlcd

NLCD landcover rasters downloaded from MRLC have default legends and symbology as shown here: http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_leg.php

However, when I extract the raster through a mask, or reproject the raster, or do similar geoprocessing, the default symbology is replaced by random colors.

How do I get this symbology back? LANDFIRE offers a table with RGB values I can join to the file that, once joined, changes the raster image back to default colors when you go through properties -> symbology -> unique values -> add all values. Any similar solution for NLCD?

Comment: Could you tell us what software you are using?

Comment: @Barbarossa I have this same question and added tags for software: ArcMap in ArcGIS 10.5

Answer (score 1):

I found that clip tool maintains colormap:

[image]

You can apply extract by mask to clipped image and add colormap, using original raster:

```
arcpy.AddColormap_management("from_clip", "nlcd_2011_landcover_2011_edition_2014_10_10.img")
```

Result:

[image]